# elasticsearch partial update with python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have a elasticsearch document in the following format. I need to partial update the "x" field and add a python dict in it.

```
{
        "_index": "gdata34",
        "_type": "gdat",
        "_id": "328091-72341-118",
        "_version": 1,
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
            "d": {
                "Thursday": {
                    "s": ""
                },
                "Email": {
                    "s": ""
                },
               "Country": {
                    "s": "US"
                },

            },
            "x": {
                "Geo": {
                    "s": "45.335428,-118.057133",
                    "g": [
                        -118.057133
                        ,
                        45.335428
                    ]
                }
            },
          }
        }
```

I tried the following code to update:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, exceptions
import pprint


elasticsearch = Elasticsearch()
doc = elasticsearch.get(index='gdata34', doc_type='gdat', id='328091-72341-7')

elasticsearch.update(index='gdata34', doc_type='gdat', id='328091-72341-7',
                     body={"script":"ctx._source.x += y",
                           "params":{"y":"z"}
                     }
                     )
elasticsearch.indices.refresh(index='gdata34')
new_doc = elasticsearch.get(index='gdata34', doc_type='gdat', id='328091-72341-7')
```

I am getting this error:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, u'ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to execute script]; nested: ScriptException[dynamic scripting for [groovy] disabled]; ')
```

What is the right way to do partial update in elasticsearch using python?

Comment: What version of ES are you using?

Answer (score 13):

For future reference, the following method of partial update worked.

```
elasticsearch.update(index='gdata34', doc_type='gdat', id='328091-72341-7',
                     body={
                         'doc': {'x': {'y':'z'}}
                     }
                     )
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [ElasticSearch docs on scripting](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#modules-scripting):

> We recommend running Elasticsearch behind an application or proxy,
>   which protects Elasticsearch from the outside world. If users are
>   allowed to run dynamic scripts (even in a search request), then they
>   have the same access to your box as the user that Elasticsearch is
>   running as. **For this reason dynamic scripting is allowed only for
>   sandboxed languages by default.**

Now, in recent ES version there has been a bug in the vulnerability in the Groovy scripting engine that allows scripts to escape the sandbox and execute shell commands as the user running the Elasticsearch Java VM - that's why the [Groovy sandbox is disabled by default in recent versions](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html), and therefore the execution of Groovy scripts passed in the request body or from the `.scripts` index. The only way to execute Groovy scripts with this default configuration is to place them in the `config/scripts/` directory on the node.

So you have two options:

- If your ES instance is **not** directly accessible and is secured behind a proxy, you can turn on Groovy sandboxing again by setting `script.groovy.sandbox.enabled: true` in `config/elasticsearch.yml` on your node(s). If your ES instance is accessible by your
- You can prepare your script and place it on the filesystem in the `config/scripts` directory of your node(s), and call it by name. See [Running Groovy Scripts without Dynamic Scripting](https://www.elastic.co/blog/running-groovy-scripts-without-dynamic-scripting) for details.

Comment: can we use the following?elasticsearch.update(index='gdata34', doc_type='gdat', id='328091-72341-7',
                     body={
                         'doc': {'x': {'y':'z'}}
                     }
                     )

Comment: Yes, but make sure to read the [documentation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/docs-update.html) - unless you specify `"detect_noop": true` this will always result in the document being updated, even if the merging process didn't detect any changes.

Comment: At least with ElasticSearch 2.3 (the latest version at this time), `detect_noop` is enabled by default.