# How to bulk update a single field in elasticsearch using python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

How to perform a single field bulk update in elastic search. Currently, I am trying with helper function as follows,

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers
for doc in collection_1:

   try:
       uid = int(doc["uid"])
       k.append({
                "_index": "col1",
                "_type" : "col1",
                "_id"   : uid,
                "_source": doc
            })
    except Exception as err:
       print(err)

helpers.bulk(es, k)
```

E.S version: 2.4

Comment: By default elasticsearch will replace whatever is inside `_source` if a document with same `_id`  already exist.

Comment: @GarbageCollector. While updating time I have only the updated field value and id with me. I won't get all the values

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29469218/elasticsearch-partial-update-with-python) question

Answer (score 2):

Please show your import and and your Elasticsearch version. Also your code is missing a reference to `collection1` variable. If you want to use the bulk helpers, you shall follow the syntax described in the [python bulk helpers documentation](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html).

You shall specify a field `_op_type` in your body and set it to `update` and then pass your partial document.

Answer (score 0):

You could use script for updating just required fields not all _source document

```
"script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.datetime2=new Date((long)(ctx._source.creationDate+12600000));"
    ,"lang": "painless"
}
```